# Remove tab from tabpages from current tab

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a tabcontrol from my mainform that I add user controls too. I want to be able to remove the tab from the collection from within itself. Maybe put a little x on the corner. How do you think I would go about doing that ?

This is how I add stuff to the TabPage control.

```
DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage tabPage = new DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage() { Text = room.Name, Tag = roomView };

roomView.ParentTab = tabPage;
roomView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
roomView.Settings = Settings;

tabPage.Controls.Add(roomView);
tbRooms.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "x" button out there, assign an event to it, then in the click event call something like this:

```
tbRooms.TabPages.Remove(tbRooms.SelectedTab);
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually go about this is by adding a button that will close the currently selected tab.  Use the click event on the button to run the code:

```
this.tbRooms.TabPages.RemoveAt(this.tabcontroller.SelectedIndex);
```

You may want to choose which tab to focus on after closing, this example would select the last tab in the controller:

```
this.tbRooms.SelectedIndex = this.tbRooms.TabCount-1;
```

I'm not certain about how to add the X button on the actual tab controller, probably fairly complicated.

If you want to be fancy, you can create a button for restoring closed tabs by simply making a Queue of TabPages that are removed.  Dequeue the tab on a button click and re-add to your tabcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

If you name your tabs you can also remove them by key (ie: name)

```
myTabPage.name = "WhateverTab";

MyTabControl.TabPages.RemoveByKey("WhateverTab");
```

or by index

```
MyTabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(2);
```

to remove the third tab in the control

Answer (score 1):

instead use tabpage dispose method, which work perfectly fine with static as well as dynamic tab pages.

Answer (score 1):

the following option would be very easy to just hide the tabs that are needed instead of deleting the pages and controls of a particular option. Once hidden, you will not be able to select, so problem is resolved.

this.viewRibbonPage1.Visible = false;

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem at the moment and have solved it by using the mouse_click event. When user right click on the tab it will be removed.
This is my reference [Change SelectedTab of TabControl on MouseOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662083/change-selectedtab-of-tabcontrol-on-mouseover)

```
private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {             
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
            {
                if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).IntersectsWith(mouseRect))
                {
                    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }     
        }   
    }
```