# Change SelectedTab of TabControl on MouseOver

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, tabcontrol

I have a Windows Forms project with a `TabControl`.

Does anyone know how to change the `SelectedTab` when you hover over it with the pointer?

Comment: Interesting ! , maybe you need to set and handle `tabcontrol.TabPages[0].MouseHover` for all the tabs you have in the control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use TabControl's MouseMove event to detect whether your mouse is present on any tab and then can select it:

```
private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
    {
        if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).IntersectsWith(mouseRect))
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
        {
            if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.X, e.Y))
            {
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```