# C# Switch tabs(tabcontrol) while dragging and hovering over a tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If someone can help me with this it will be much appreciated, all I want is code that will allow me to change tab pages while dragging a treenode from a treeview that is OUTSIDE the tabcontrol AND hovering over a tabpage that is NOT already open(selected).

Comment: The part about switching tap page on mouse over has been answered before... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9662219/1246574.

Comment: You need to handle DragOver event on the tabcontrol similar to the mousemove in Jim's comment.

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried so we can see what is not working?

Comment: 1. This question I asked is about DRAGGING A TREENODE AND HOVERING OVER A TAB WHICH WILL OPEN THE TABPAGE NOT ONE OR THE OTHER. 2. No I'm not going to post you the code

Comment: Also I know I need tabcontrol dragover and treeview item drag. The problem is upon dragging the node and hovering over the treeview view. does not change the tab despite the fact the bool statement that I used to check while dragging it says otherwise

Comment: If you can't post the code you've tried, it is very hard for us to try to help you.  You're claiming you code doesn't work even though it should, but without seeing your code we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DragOver event will be fired when the mouse moves over the tabcontrol while the drag action is still in effect.  You can use similar logic to the mousemove logic in [Change SelectedTab of TabControl on MouseOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662083/tabcontrol-selectedtab-change-on-mouse-over/9662219#9662219) in your DragOver handler to make the tabs switch.

Edit:

I did a little MSDN research and found a likely issue.  DragOver coordinates are ScreenCoordinates while the tab rectangle in the sample code is in client coordinates.  You will need to convert the drag coordinates before the hit check.

```
            Point clientPoint = tabControl1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

Edit2:

Put together a trivial app with a TreeView and a TabControl and the following DragOver handler switched tabs correctly as I dragged over the tabs:

```
    private void tabControl1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;

        Point clientPoint = tabControl1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
        {
            if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(clientPoint) && tabControl1.SelectedIndex != i)
            {
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tried that already using a bool value to check and all. Didn't work

Comment: I'd swap the two conditions. `if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex != i && tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(clientPoint))`.