# C# Switch tabs(tabcontrol) while dragging a watermark picbox and hovering over a tab

Tags: c#, picturebox, tabcontrol

In one of my posts(the link below), I ask how to change tabs while dragging a treenode and hovering over a tab. Now I want do the same thing except with a watermark picbox that is inside another picturebox(a parent sort of speak) that inside a tab.There are two tab pages, two "parent" picboxes(one foreach tab) and one dynamically added picbox on first tab. For more detail read the numbered list below also the code you will need is below the link.

1. The parent picboxes in both tabs are maxed out in both height and in width to fit the whole tabpage(NOT the header area). The watermark image size is below in the code. Also the watermark is dynamically added.
2. The reason this semi-copy of the older post failed is because the watermark drag enter event was never called. Meaning the tab never opened after the pic was dragged and was hovering over one of the tabs.Though I'm not 100% sure if I should use the same event with picboxes.
3. I want to know how I can open tabs while dragging a picbox and hovering over a tab and be able to drop the watermark image on the 2nd parent picbox in tabpage#2 and remove the watermark image in tabpage 1 if there is a copy of the same watermark image.

[C# Switch tabs(tabcontrol) while dragging and hovering over a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308213/c-sharp-switch-tabstabcontrol-while-dragging-and-hovering-over-a-tab/33308531#33308531)

Point mousePos;
        bool Movedummytonewtabpic = false;

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox picdrag1 = new PictureBox();
        picdrag1.Name = "dummytest";
        picdrag1.Image = Properties.Resources._previmg;
        picdrag1.Size = new Size(52, 42);
        picdrag1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        picdrag1.MouseDown += picdrag1_MouseDown;
        picdrag1.MouseMove += picdrag1_MouseMove;
        picdrag1.DragEnter += picdrag1_DragEnter;
        picdrag1.Location = new Point(168, 151);   
        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(picdrag1);
    }

    private void picdrag1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        //DragDropEffects.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        Movedummytonewtabpic = true;
    }

    private void picdrag1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousePos = e.Location;
    }

    private void picdrag1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int dx = e.X - mousePos.X;
            int dy = e.Y - mousePos.Y;
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left + dx, pictureBox1.Top + dy);
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Movedummytonewtabpic == true )
        {
            //e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;

            Point clientPoint = tabControl1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
            {
                if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(clientPoint) && tabControl1.SelectedIndex != i)
                {
                    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A **Drag** operation is **not** being used here, so the DragOver() event subsequently will never fire.  You're simply changing the Location() of the PictureBox.  I suppose you could simulate a drag operation by checking `dx` and `dy` in your MouseMove event instead.

Comment: I'd appreciate the suggestion, but with all due respect I'm looking for possible solutions not partial answers